# PropertyGrid BrowsableAttributes Bug?

Tags: propertygrid, browsable, xmlattributecollection

This seems like a bug:

the code below works fine:

```
this.propertyGrid1.SelectedObject = new Button();
```

the code below doesn't:

```
this.propertyGrid1.BrowsableAttributes = new AttributeCollection(
     new CategoryAttribute("Layout"));
this.propertyGrid1.SelectedObject = new Button();
```

Size, Location, ... Properties in PropertyGrid can't be expanded.

Comment: I think it's because the sub objects properties (X, Y, etc.) in Size and Location are not in the Layout Category, which makes BrowsableAttributes less interesting to use IMHO.